# UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "sections"

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson as part of a spring boot app.  I am turning JSON into Java, and I am getting this error. I did some research, but I still don't understand what is going wrong or how to fix it.

Here is the JSON fragment:

```
      "dataBlock": {
        "sections": [
          {
            "info": "",
            "prompt": "",
            "name": "First Section",
            "sequence": 0,
            "fields": [],
            "gatingConditions": [],
            "guid": "480d160c-c34f-4022-97b0-e8a1f28c49ae",
            "id": -2
          }
        ],
        "prompt": "",
        "id": -1,
        "name": ""
      }
```

So my Java object for this "dataBlock" element:

```
public class DataBlockObject {

private int id;
private String prompt;
private String name;
private List<SectionObject> sections;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPrompt() {
    return prompt;
}
public void setPrompt(String prompt) {
    this.prompt = prompt;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public List<SectionObject> getSections() {
    return sections;
}
public void setSections(List<SectionObject> sections) {
    this.sections = sections;
}
}
```

And the Section object is this:

```
public class SectionObject {

private int id;
private String name;
private String prompt;
private String info;
private int sequence;
private List<FieldObject> fields;
private List<GatingConditionObject> gatingConditions;
private String guid;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPrompt() {
    return prompt;
}
public void setPrompt(String prompt) {
    this.prompt = prompt;
}
public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}
public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}
public int getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}
public void setSequence(int sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}
public List<FieldObject> getFields() {
    return fields;
}
public void setFields(List<FieldObject> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}
public List<GatingConditionObject> getGatingConditions() {
    return gatingConditions;
}
public void setGatingConditions(List<GatingConditionObject> gatingConditions) {
    this.gatingConditions = gatingConditions;
}
public String getGuid() {
    return guid;
}
public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
}
}
```

So it seems to me that Jackson would make a DataBlockObject,  map the obvious elemenets, and create an array that I have clearly marked as a List  named sections.  -- just like the JSON shows.

Now the error is:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "sections" (class com.gridunity.workflow.bean.json.SectionObject), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "gatingConditions", "sequence", "prompt", "fields", "id", "info", "guid", "name"])
```

Now according to that error it would seem that one of my 8 elements should be named "sections" - But that's not one of my elements.  It clearly has a problem with my List of Sections,   but I cant figure out what it is.

Can someone explain WHY this is happening,  especially sence it looks like I have my structure correct,  and how to fix this.  I have seen this on other posts:

```
 objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

But that seems incredibly wrong as I know all of my properties.

Comment: It seems that the real JSON have a fields named sections inside the section itseld (i.e. as a sibling of the 8 known properties gatingConditions, sequance, etc.

Comment: can you add `@JsonProperty("sections")` to the getters and `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to the class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON itself has another `sections` field in one or more of the `dataBlock.sections` items. If you don't have control over the construction of the JSON object, you'll need to add a `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation on the `SectionObject` class so that when the JSON object has fields that aren't specified in the POJO, it won't throw an error during deserialization.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SectionObject {
    // class members and methods here
}
```